# How to make a border in a SKScene using a custom image

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

So I want to create a border around my SKScene so I created a png file that has a blue border with an opacity of 0.8 around the edges and is clear on the inside. I then added it to my SKScene after adding my background image. The border goes right on top of the background like I want but when I create new SKSpriteNodes their image goes over the border instead of underneath it. I tried setting the zPosition of the border but that just causes no new SKSpriteNodes to show up, even though the inside of the border is clear. What I want is to have new SKSpriteNode's to go under the border, they should still be visible a little because the border has an opacity of 0.8, and still be visible inside the border. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or how to do this right?

Thanks!

Comment: can you post an image what you exactly want and what is actually doing which gives us a bigger picture to solve it easily

Answer (score 0):

To do what you say you should create 4 images , namely: the bottom edge, right edge , top and left edge ment .

Make height and width according to the size that you gave to the scene.

After that instantiates 4 variables and put everything in place.

```
var borderBottom = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "borderbottomimage")
var borderRight = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "borderrightimage")
var borderUp = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "borderupimage")
var borderLeft = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "borderleftimage")

//in didView 
borderBottom = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMinY(self.frame))
borderRight = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
borderUp = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
borderLeft = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMinX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))

self.addChild(borderBottom)
self.addChild(borderRight)
self.addChild(borderUp)
self.addChild(borderLeft)
```

Set zIndex and other parameters as desired.
So ' works